# Navigation drawer fragments overlap even with replace()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer in an activity. The activity's layout has a relative layout for a fragment. The id of relativelayout is `mainContent` in which I load the fragment(call it fragA) in the `onCreate()` of the activity. I have this same fragment also in the navigation drawer along with other navigation items. It is loaded oncreate of activity and can also be loaded from navigation drawer.

On selecting the navigation items, I replace the fragment in the `mainContent` which is the relativelayout in the activity with `replace()`. In the navigation drawer, the 0th item is the "fragB"(the same as fragA but in nav drawer). Second is another fragment(fragC). When I select fragB "more than once" and then select fragA and press back button, fragB and fragC overlap.

And also I have to keep pressing back button to go to initial screen because every time I select an item from nav drawer, new fragments fragBs and fragCs are created. Not replaced. I replace them in `mainContent`(first relative layout) in the activity's layout. I'm using `FrameLayout` for the fragments.

This is the activity's layout in which I place fragments:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.prematixsofs.taxiapp.DateVehiclePicker">
<!-- The main content view -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"></include>
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <!-- Profile Box -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#ff02c7c4"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/user" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/viewProfile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="View Profile"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileBox"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/invisibleTextViewId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Activity's code where I load the fragA:

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainContent, new DateTimePicker(),"tags").commit();
```

This is nav drawer onSelect:

```
  private void selectItemFromDrawer(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position){
        case 0: fragment = new DateTimePicker();
            break;
        case 1: fragment = new PreferencesFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerPane);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DateVehiclePicker.this);

            alertDialog.setTitle("Logout");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to Logout?");
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    sessionManager.logoutUser();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
    }
    if(fragment!=null)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerPane);
    }
```

This is where I set listener for nav drawer:

```
 mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItemFromDrawer(position);

        }
    });
```

I call the method `selectItemFromDrawer(position);`

Comment: what are you doing in case 2 and have you called this method somewhere. Are you getting any error??

Comment: @VivekMishra It's to close the nav drawer and display a dialog. `case 2:` is not for a fragment. I'm not getting any error.

Comment: drawer closing code is already written at last line and also tell where you have called this method

Comment: The method is in the class `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`. I have removed the close code. I dont think that it's causing a problem

Comment: so you are saying that selectItemFromDrawer is an override method??

Comment: @VivekMishra No, I call the method with listener. I've edited the question. The code is at the end of question

Comment: so are you getting any error?

Comment: @VivekMishra No ..It's still creating multiple new repeated fragments. Every time an item is selected, the method is called again and maybe new object is created inside the `if`. I declared it outside but am getting `commit() already called`

Comment: try removing backstack line from replace method

Comment: @VivekMishra Yeah that will work. But I want the fragments to be added to backstack because when back is pressed from a fragment it has to go back to previous fragment.

Comment: see this link for adding fragment to backstack https://github.com/rathodchintan/Fragment-Back-Stack

Comment: @VivekMishra Ok. thank you

Comment: No..I will think of something eklse

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are creating **new object for fragment transaction everytime** you are trying to change fragment. Make it global in your code and use same instance everywhere.
Here is the code with switch case instead of if else

```
 private void displayView(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                  fragment=new FragmentHome();
                    title="Home";
                    break;
                case 1:
                   fragment=new FragmentAddress();
                    title="Update Address";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment=new FragmentHelpList();
                    title="My Helps";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment=new FragmentCompletedHelps();
                    title="History";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fragment=new FragmentSupport();
                    title="Account & Support";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    fragment=new FragmentAbout();
                    title="About";
                    break;
                case 6:
                        appSharedPreferences.setSession(false);
                    finish();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                // set the toolbar title
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
            }
```

Make the fragment variable global too

Comment: I'm getting `commit() already called` error. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: don't call commit every time. I can give you an example with switch case. You can follow it accordingly

Comment: It didn't work. I've edited my question to show what I've done. Please see if this is what you said. It's still creating new repeated fragments

Answer (score 0):

You must handle BackStack for this you must clear all fragment which is on stack when you added or replace with main fragment

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Logg.e(TAG, getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
        try {
            if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
            {
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
            }

            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            } else
            {   Exit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing R.id.mainContent to R.id.container. I have similar setup but it is working fine with R.id.container.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                new Registration_fragment()).commit();
```

and you have to replace FragA (not add) also initially during load.

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContent, new DateTimePicker(),"tags").commit();
```